# inheriting a GUI class in LWUIT 1.5

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I'm trying to inherit a class that I made in the GUI Resource Editor of Lwuit to extend some functionality. I want to do something like:

```
public class MyCustomGUIForm extend CustomGUIForm{...}
```

Where `CustomGUIForm` its a `Form` that I create in the Resource Editor. Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to explain you what I do for extend some functionallity in the `Forms`that I create  with the Resource Editor.
When you build a NetBeansProject with the Resource Editor, you get a `StateMachine` class wich allows you to modify/add some aspects of your apps navigation.
In the `StateMachine` class you can find a lot of methods related to the elements that you create in the Resource Editor.

For example:

You create a `Form` in the Resource Editor, called CustomGUIForm. After you save the .res, you  should find some methods in the `StateMachine` class called `beforeCustomGUIForm` `postCustomGUIForm` and `exitGUIForm`, with this methods you can use the `Form` and add some functionality. You can observe that in `StateMachine` there are other methods for Commands that you build in the Resource Editor, ActionListeners, etc etc. Take a look to the overriden methods for the `StateMachine`, they could be usefull for you.

Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: Hi jmunoz! Thanks for your reply. I already use all the functionality that you say. I will explain a little bit more what I'm trying to do. I'm developing an app that shows maps using Nutiteq maps lib, so I want to implement some interfaces in different Forms. A fast solution was to implement the interfaces in StateMachine class and ask in each of the interface's functions about the current form... but I think it isn't a seamless solution. any idea?

Comment: I usually create other classes that help me to manage this Forms. I can do this because I create an object of this class and call the methods that I want to use in the StateMachine's methods (before, post, etc). You can try to do that

Comment: Hi jmunoz and thnx for your reply again. Your solution make me realize that there was other way to solve my problem whithout extend ResourceEditor Forms. I've created a MapComponent (extended from Lwuit Component) that implement all the needed interfaces and i've placed it into a generic MapForm at runtime. I think this will be a good solution for my problem but i still wondering if there's any way to extend a ResourceEditor Form. Any way, tvm for your reply again!.

Answer (score 0):

While jmunoz gave the better answer for this just for completeness you can indeed inherit and override any component created by the resource editor.

In your Statemachine override:

```
protected Component createComponentInstance(String componentType, Class cls) {
     if(cls == Form.class) {
           return new MyFormInstance();
     }
     return null;
}
```

There is one drawback in this approach, all forms will now be `MyFormInstance`. This is or usable for some use cases and not so much for others.